# "You are not authorized to access this page" how to hide this message in drupal

Tags: drupal

"You are not authorized to access this page" how to hide this message in drupal

Comment: Open access to user. Give more description for your task: what page, what module, what user, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose a custom 403 Page in the settings, for D6 it's admin/settings/error-reporting and admin/config/system/site-information for Drupal 7.